# When querying a MySql DB VBScript is returning asian characters instead of English

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I am using VBScript to query a MySQL database that contains only English characters. The query is basically: SELECT * FROM table name PROCEDURE ANALYSE(1,1)

When I run the query directly on the DB it returns the expected results. However, when the query is run through VBScript it returns gibberish (Chinese?). I know for a fact the DB only contains English as I am the one who built it. I've run numerous other queries against the same table and haven't had any problems. Its only when I run the PROCEDURE ANALYSE query that it returns something unexpected.

The VBScript code is as follows:

```
strSQLcommand = "SELECT * FROM " & strTempTableName & " PROCEDURE ANALYSE(1,1)"
otRecordset.Open strSQLcommand,Connection

If Not otRecordset.EOF Then
otRecordset.movefirst
Do While NOT otRecordset.EOF
wscript.echo otRecordset(0).value
wscript.echo  otRecordset(1).value
otRecordset.Movenext
Loop
End If
```

I've never had a problem with returning values from any other table in this DB. I've run this query numerous times and always get the same results which has me perplexed.

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, it turns out it has nothing to do with the DB per se.

I decided to start checking the data types that were being returned using the VBScript VarTYpe() method. The fields that were returning "gibberish/Chinese" had a data type of 8092. Basically, a byte array. Sprinkling a little Google fairy dust led me to this function:

```
Function C8209toStr(body8209)
    If VarType(body8209) = 8209 Then
        Dim i
        ReDim aOut(UBound(body8209))
        For i = 1 to UBound(body8209) + 1
             aOut(i-1) = chr(ascb(midb(body8209,i,1)))
        Next
    C8209toStr = Join(aOut, "")
    End If
End Function
```

Hope that helps whoever else comes along!